# mysql docker всегда перезагружается

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu, docker

Стек ubuntu+laravel+mysql+docker+nginx

когда запускаю команду docker-compose up -d выводит что все done все образы запускаются но mysql всегда перезагружается выводя одну и ту же ошибку

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOQAeP3qkP0&list=PLd2_Os8Cj3t9Ert8mBlNl1UqwllyP1Tm_

Все сделал по этому видеоролику

Ошибка: в logs

```
2022-09-26 05:47:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-09-26 05:47:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-09-26 05:47:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-09-26T05:47:43.328109Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-09-26T05:47:43.329625Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-09-26T05:47:43.337528Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-09-26T05:47:43.410486Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 5.7.39, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
2022-09-26T05:47:43.410513Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-09-26T05:47:43.853682Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-09-26T05:47:43.853859Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-09-26T05:47:43.853880Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-26T05:47:43.854574Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./_docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    ports:
      - "8876:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
    container_name: project_nginx

  app:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: _docker/app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
    depends_on:
        -  db
    container_name: project_app

  db:
      image: mysql:8.0
      restart: always
      volumes:
          - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: lardocker
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      ports:
          - 8101:3306
      command: mysqld --character-set-server=UTF8MB4 --collation-server=UTF8MB4_unicode_ci
      container_name: project_db
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      apt-utils \
      libpq-dev \
      libpng-dev \
      libzip-dev \
      zip unzip \
      git && \
      docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
      docker-php-ext-install bcmath && \
      docker-php-ext-install gd && \
      docker-php-ext-install zip && \
      apt-get clean && \
      rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

COPY ./_docker/app/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

# Install composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    --filename=composer \
    --install-dir=/usr/local/bin

WORKDIR /var/www
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lardocker
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Answer (score 0):

Была проблема с постоянным перезапуском контейнера с базой. Причина оказалась в ограничении RAM на сервере. Увеличил до 1 гига - заработало.